Alarm issue .it is not working when app is closed
iam developing an alarm app it is producing the sound when app is opening but when we closing the app doesn't producing the sound.can anyone help what packages to be installed and what should be changed to get the sound when app is closed
i need what packages to be installed

Your question is not very precise however I am taking some preconditions in here that you might do:
Assumption
I guess you are having an Activity that is being started.
Inside this activity you provide a brief visualization where an alarm-time can be set by a user.
There might also be an activate and deactivate button.
I assume that you have the "countdown"-code inside your activity and under this circumstance this will be the issue.
If you "exit" your applications activity the onStop will be called on your activity, causing the "onCreate" code to be stopped.
You might want to start a Foreground-Service when the user starts the countdown.
Activity Lifecycle vs. Services
Please have a look into the following Guides first to gain a brief overview about what happens to an activity at lifecycle-changes and which services exist.
Lifecycle:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle
Services:
https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/services
If you are still facing issues, please provide a code example with a detailed problem description.
